# Threshold variable for monitoring CPU shell script

Tags: linux, shell, variables, cpu, monitoring

I'm doing a CPU monitoring shell script that will write a log with the following information:

> INFO for CPU < 70% WARNING for CPU (70 80)% ERROR for CPU > 90%.

I need to know if I can be create 3 variables `$INFO`, `$WARNING` and `$ERROR` that will simplify the script.

```
case "$CPU" in

   $WARNING      )
                echo "$DATE WARNING CPU USAGE is $CPU"
                ;;
   $ERROR        )
                echo "$DATE ERROR CPU USAGE is $CPU"
                ;;


   $INFO         )
                echo "$DATE INFO CPU USAGE is $CPU"
                ;;
esac
```

Comment: Yes you can set three variables. No, using `case` to test against them is not appropriate, as you actually want to do relational testing - e.g. `if (( ${current_usage} < ${INFO} )) ...`; `case` tests for string matches, not numerical ordering.

Comment: What are the possible values and the format of `$CPU`?